# Can I refer to a variable using a string?

Tags: javascript

Say I have the following JS:

> ```
> var foo_index = 123;
> var bar_index = 456;
> ```

And the following HTML:

> ```
> <div id="foo"></div>
> <div id="bar"></div>
> ```

Then I'd like to say this:

> ```
> thisIndex = this.id + '_index'
> ```

And I'd like `thisIndex` to be a number. How do I turn the string, which is exactly the variable name, into a variable?

Comment: Semi-related comment: this question has made me realize the power of the `$` symbol in PHP.

Comment: power? I'd call that 'misuse'

Comment: It's possible, but bad design. (even usually in PHP, BoltClock) You might want to use an array instead (javascript array can be used as hash maps) or perhaps some other feature of javascript (there are a lot of possibilities in javascript and your sample does not really show what you want to be doing).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can. If foo_index and bar_index are global variables, you can simply do:

```
var thisIndex = window[this.id + '_index'];
```

Comment: That's quite helpful to know. Thanks.

Comment: +1 This should have been the right answer since it doesn't require the asker to change his code.

Comment: Don't see why I didn't accept this as the answer the first time around. I didn't use this method that time, but it's quite a gem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 11):

You should put the variables in an object, like this:

```
var indices = { 
    foo: 123,
    bar: 456
};

var thisIndex = indices[this.id];
```

This code uses <strike>JSON syntax</strike> an object literal to define an object with two properties and uses `[]` to access a property by name.

You can also write

```
var indices = new Object;
indices.foo = 123;
indices["bar"] = 456;
```

Comment: You got it completely backwards. It's JSON that uses a subset of the Javascript syntax. This is a Javascript object, and it has nothing at all to do with JSON.

Comment: @Guffa: I realize that.  However, the syntax is usually referred to as JSON syntax.  What would you call it?

Comment: @SLaks: It's an object literal. The syntax has been around long before JSON existed, so it's only very recently that people have started to (incorrectly) refer to it as JSON syntax.

Comment: Just to clarify: JSON is simply a textual representation of a JS object. It's a serialized form of an object.

Comment: Doesn't JSON just mean JavaScript Object Notation? 'JSON syntax' is kind of a redundant acronym, but since object notation is exactly what you used in the declaration you were right to refer to it as JSON in the first place.

Comment: @Keith: No, it's not right. It's **not** JSON. In fact, the code that SLaks showed doesn't even work if you try to use it as JSON. The JSON syntax is a subset of the Javascript syntax, and the code for this object literal is outside of that subset.

Answer (score 5):

you can try using the eval function:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

it does exactly what you need.

Comment: If you're thinking of using *eval()*, chances are there's a better way of doing what you're trying to do (in this case, SLaks' answer).  [Eval is Evil](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx), by Eric Lippert is a good read on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, you can use the `eval` function to evaluate a string:

```
thisIndex = eval(this.id + '_index');
```

However, using the `eval` function is generally a sign of badly constructed code. I think that you should use an associative array instead:

```
var numbers = { foo: 123, bar: 456 };
thisIndex = numbers[this.id];
```

Comment: rather, use JSON.parse it's a lot safer than eval. download json2.js on google.

Comment: @Martin: *JSON.parse()* wouldn't help here, it will only parse a JSON string, which isn't the intent.

Answer (score 1):

```
window["myvar"] = 'hello';

alert(myvar);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what do you want to achieve, but maybe this approach could be better (it depends on some factors like version of HTML you use as [@Andy E](https://stackoverflow.com/users/94197/andy-e) points in comment below):

```
<div id="foo" index="123"></div>
<div id="bar" index="456"></div>
<script>
   var fooIndex = document.getElementById("foo").getAttribute("index");
</script>
```

Here value of `index` is kept together with corresponding HTML element.

Comment: Custom attributes are not allowed in HTML4 and will invalidate your markup.  However, it would be valid HTML5 if you prefix the attribute names with *data-*, e.g. `data-index="123"`.

Comment: This is why I wrote "would be better". "could" would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
// put your properties in an object of some kind
var dictionary = 
{
    foo_index: 123,
    bar_index: 456
};

// you can set further properties with property syntax
dictionary.again_index = 789;

// or dictionary syntax - same result
dictionary['another_index'] = 012;

// then function to get the number value from the index name becomes
var thisIndex = Number(dictionary[this.id + '_index']);
```

Comment: Why are you calling `Number`?

Comment: @SLaks - yeah, I don't really need to, just being explicit as the OP said that they wanted a number back.